# Boundaries in Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps for my website and I want to create boundaries of towns and cities, as shown in the screenshot below.

**Problem:** There seems not to be any feature in the V3 API to perform this function. I believe it involves retrieving the Latlng of the path that forms a polygon around the area.
How then do you get the Latlng of the points needed?

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: How would you define the boundary of a city?  And what does that have to do with your picture?

Comment: I meant to say the boundary of a neighborhood, not city. I want to achieve the same effect as in the screenshot, so the boundary of a zip code is not specific enough.

Comment: Ok, how would you define the boundary of Boston?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, assuming you already have a path defined as a Polyline, you can then call the [.getPath() function](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline) which returns an MVCArray of LatLng objects.  I assume that answers your question *"How then do you get the Latlng of the points needed?"*